# Can I create an s3 bucket policy that blocks all non-encrypted uploads, but allows Athena DB engine to write a non-encrypted file?

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I have an s3 bucket policy that blocks all non-encrypted uploads.
Athena needs to use this bucket. And when the service that's using athena is running, all is working correctly.
However, when the Athena DB is initialised, it creates and drops a file in the s3 bucket. 
something like this : `18b21651-f514-481a-aa62-ef26db73c6c0.txt` with a description of the DBs.

Since this text file is not encrypted, I get an Access Denied Error. But I cannot control Athena to encrypt this file.

I'm looking for a policy that will allow this file to be uploaded unencrypted, but all other files have to be encrypted.

I'm not sure what `principle` to use for this policy since I cannot use the IAM_ROLE that the service calling Athena is using. What is the 'native' athena role/user?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "deny unencrypted object upload",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

error observed:

```
aws_athena_database.main: reason: Access denied when writing to location: s3://bucketname/36dc88f0-a7b7-4956-95c9-062a8ac46d5f.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `NotPrincipal` key to exempt Athena from your "Deny" policy:

```
{
    "Sid": "deny unencrypted object upload",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": "*",
    "NotPrincipal": "athena.amazonaws.com",
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
            "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up in using something slightly modified from this, but the addition of the NotPrinciple attribute worked great. thanks.